# How to set focus on different element while click on an anchor tag with href

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

i wants to set focus on the parent div when someone click on the link how can i

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#about">Link to the parent div</a>
</li>

<div id="#parent">
    <div id="about">dummy data</div>
    <div id="news">dummy data</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/PGzwc/

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Mr Lister and mrtsherman have different ideas about what you want to achieve? Or maybe the question is, WHY do you want to achieve that? Is it impossible to change the HTML itself, but you can add Javascript, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `document.getElementById('parent').focus()`. See the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGzwc/2/).

But what is supposed to happen when the div gets the focus? Divs don't change anything when they get focus!

Edit:
If you want the `<a>` to scroll the document to the top of `parent` when clicked, this is what you need: `document.body.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('parent').offsetTop); return false;` See the [once more updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGzwc/8/).

But if that's not what you want either, just say so!

Comment: When he said `focus` he meant have the link navigate to an anchor with id `parent` instead of `about`. Confusing I know. I have no idea what he is trying to accomplish with this, but he won't change his link to target `parent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Animated jQuery solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGzwc/5/

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();       
    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $('#parent').offset().top }, 'slow');
});​
```

Just change

```
<a href="#about">Home</a>  
          to 
<a href="#parent">Home</a>
```

The `#` tag tells the browser to search for an element with that `id` and bring it to the top of the page.

Comment: i wants to set focus on parent but link should be to that child

Comment: how can i achieve this i have created its fiddle please have a look a that http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/PGzwc/1/

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are trying to do, but why do you care? Just set the link to target the correct location. It doesn't make any sense to create an anchor that goes to the wrong location.

Comment: Okay, posted animated version of it. Still have no idea why you would do this.